# Address different for external function

Tags: c++, function, memory-address

I want to determine the position of the `LoadLibraryA` function relative to its container dll(kernel32). This is what I have tried (code used for debugging):

```
int main(){
    unsigned char *kernel=(unsigned char *)LoadLibraryA("kernel32");
    cout<<GetModuleHandleA(0)<<" "<<(unsigned int*)LoadLibraryA<<"  "<<(unsigned int*)GetProcAddress((HINSTANCE)kernel,"LoadLibraryA")<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:`0x400000 0x420144  0x75c95980 0x75c80000`

It is obvious that only `GetProcAddr` returns the "real" address of the function because it is closer to kernel's base address(and because Dependency Walker says so).

What happend then to the simple `LoadLibraryA` function (the one with the lower address)? Why does it have such a strange address? 
I always thought that when a exe starts it calls LoadLibrary and GetProcAddr 'behind' the scenes and changes all references to that desired function with the one found in the dll(after taking care of the random address at which the dll has been loaded).

Correct me: I think that somehow kernel32 is statically linked so all of the used functions are copied in the end binary,thus explaining why the address of `LoadLibrary` looks relative to the base of the exe.

**EDIT**
It looks like LoadLibraryA is just a wrapper for the real function. This is what ida shows about `LoadLibraryA`:
[image]
It is a plain jump to another address. Is this `__imp_LoadLibraryA` a marker,that at execution will be replaced with `LoadLibraryA`'s address?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it is.